# fatoração com laços

Tags: c

estou estutando o livro 6º edição de C como programar dos irmãos Deitel e estou com duvida em um exercicio, o exercicio é o 4.14 do capitulo 4 que é sobre fatoração, ele pede um programa que o usuario digite um numero e esse numero seja fatorado, por exemplo se o usuario digitar o numero 5, o programa ira fazer 5*4*3*2*1 resultando em 120.
Se alguem poder me dar alguma **dica** e nao **resposta** eu ficarei muito grato obrigado:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, num, aux1=0, fat=0, aux=0;

    printf("digite um numero para ser fatorado:\n");
    scanf("%i", &num);
    printf("\nvamos fatorar entao o numero %i:\n\n", num);

    for(i=num;i>=1;i--)
    {
        aux=i;
        fat=aux*i;
        printf("%i! ", fat);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Execute seu algoritmo em um papel e veja o que você está fazendo de errado.

Comment: 1a. dica: do jeito que está sendo usada, a variável `aux` não está servindo para nada. Mas nem precisa dela. O algoritmo pode ser mais simples que isto. No fim, vai ter que existir uma resposta.

Comment: Um comentário rápido. Em matemática se usa o termo "fatorar" significa decompor um inteiro em números primos. Por exemplo, 12 = 3*2*2. O que você está pedindo é o fatorial.

Comment: Segue o que diz o @Beterraba é a melhor forma de te ajudar em algoritmos pequenos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note o que está a fazer:

Suponha num = 5;

```
   for(i=num;i>=1;i--)
    {
        aux=i;
        fat=aux*i;
        printf("\n%d ", fat);
    }
```

Faça o teste de mesa:

```
i=5         |    i=4            |  ...
aux=5       |   aux=4           |
fat=5*5???  |  fat=4*4          |
```

O que procura é isso:

```
i=5         |    i=4            |  ...
aux=5       |   aux=fat   (5)   |
fat=5       |  fat=aux*i (5*4)  |
```

Note que há varias variáveis desnecessárias e não se esqueça: `0! = 1`.

Dica: não precisa da variável aux, muito menos a aux1 que sequer usou.

Comment: ok obrigado pela dica irei fazer os teste de messa =)

Answer (score 1):

Minhas dicas:

1. Qual é o fatorial de 0? Esse seria um valor melhor para inicializar fat, já que assim você imprime a resposta correta se o laço não rodar nenhuma vez.
2. Repare como o resultado final de `fat` depende apenas do último valor de `aux` , que depende apenas do último valor de `i`. Acho que não foi pra isso que você criou o `fat`...
3. Eu prefiro iterar de 1 a N ao invés de N a 1. Assim fica mais fácil escrever uma invariante para o valor de `fat`. Se você não quiser pensar na invariante então tanto faz, obviamente)

---

Dica de C:

Você pode declarar variáveis depos de qualquer `{`. Não precisa ser tudo no topo da função:

```
{int i; for(i=n; i >= 1; i--){
   int aux = /* ... */
}}
```

Além disso , se você não estiver usando o Visual Studio, você pode compilar o seu programa usando o padrão C99 que permite declarar variáveis no meio da função

```
int num;
scanf("%d", &num);

for(int i=n; i >= 1; i--);
```

Comment: minha duvida é o seguinte agora, eu nao sei como q eu vo pegar o 5 4 3 2 1 e multiplicar cada um deles a minha ideia é que eu use um auxiliar para armazenar eles por exemplo no primeiro laço eu guardo o 5 no segundo eu guardo 5*4 e assim vai até chegar no 120*1 o problema é que ele nao armazena ele faz 5*5 cinco vezes e 4*4 cinco vezes e assim vai

Comment: @LeonardoV.DeGasperin: O que você quer fazer é o correto mas é difícil dar uma dica sem dar a resposta toda de uma vez. Então uma pergunta: Pra que serve cada uma das variáveis que você criou? Qual é o valor que cada uma delas vai ter ao lono do programa?